# Datagridview not updated on form that already open

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have created an application that update the logs form whenever the email are successfully send. My code is something like this:

**mailSender.cs**

```
     void Serche() 
     {
      {
       //perform thread background ip scanner
      }
      if (InvokeRequired){
      this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
        {
            sendReport();
        }));
      }
     }

    public void sendReport()
    {
        //some codes to trigger time schedule to send report

        ExportToExcel(filePath);
        int milliseconds = 2000;
        Thread.Sleep(milliseconds);
        sendMail(filename);
    }

    private void sendMail(string filename)
    {
        string getFilePath = @"D:\Report\" + filename;
        string status = "send";
        try
        {
          // send email filename as attachment
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            status = "Fail";
        }
        sendMailReport(filename, DateTime.Now, mailStat);
    }

    private void sendMailReport(string fileName, DateTime dateDelivered, string status)
    {
        //mailLog updateLogs = new mailLog(); 
        updateLogs.updateMailLogs(fileName,dateDelivered,status);
    }
```

**mailLog.cs**

```
    public void updateMailLogs(string _fileName, DateTime _dateDelivered, string _status)
    {
        int num = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();       
        dataGridView1.Rows[num].Cells[0].Value = _fileName;  
        dataGridView1.Rows[num].Cells[1].Value = _dateDelivered;    
        dataGridView1.Rows[num].Cells[2].Value = _status;
        dataGridView1.Refresh();
    }
```

I have debug the code line by line and found out that all parameters successfully retrieve in my updateMailLogs method, but not sure why it didnt update my datagridview. Does anyone have any idea why? Please advise.

**SOLVED**

credit to @shell who enlightened me the answer to this question.

problem:-
1- If the form is already open, then I cannot create another object of mailLog form and call updateMailLogs method.
2- This will not update your grid data. Because the both object reference are different.

solution:-
1- Need to call that method from object of mailLog form which is currently loaded.

```
private void sendMailReport(string fileName, DateTime dateDelivered,string status)
{
if (Application.OpenForms["mailLog"] != null)
   ((mailLog)Application.OpenForms["mailLog"]).updateLogs.updateMailLogs(fileName,dateDelivered,status);
}
```

Comment: Any difference if you do `dataGridView1.Rows.Add(_fileName, _dateDelivered, _Status);` [I have never had to manually refresh this way...]

Comment: @AustinFrench yes, I already tied using that method,but the result is still the same. It didn't refresh the data gridview.

Comment: Hmm, @Ren are you in a try catch? Do you have exactly 3 columns to the dgv? I used your method (copy paste) from a button with fake attributes, and no issues...

Comment: @AustinFrench yes, I already double check the columns, and I have exactly 3. Maybe there's effect if both of these mailSender.cs and mailLog.cs are in different separated forms? correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Should be fine, but to clarify there is no try, catch, or finally statements anywhere to catch this?

Comment: Note, every time you call sendMailReport method you are creating a new instance of mainLog class!!! That means, there are no old data in this class!!!

Comment: @LevZ yes,TQ. I already place the mailLog class at Initialize state. But still the datagridview did not update the row. =(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provided code does not help to understand what you have done exactly. I mean you are executing method `sendMailReport`. That method will creates object of `mailLog` class on every execution. this may lost your existing data. It is better to create your `mailLog` class object out side of your `sendMailReport` method block and just execute `updateMailLogs` method only.

```
mailLog updateLogs = new mailLog();
private void sendMailReport(string fileName, DateTime dateDelivered,string status)
{        
    updateLogs.updateMailLogs(fileName,dateDelivered,status);
}
```

---

**EDITED:**

if the form is already loaded then you should call method like this. here, you don't need to create a new object of `mailLog` class.

```
private void sendMailReport(string fileName, DateTime dateDelivered,string status)
{        
    ((mailLog)Application.OpenForms["mailLog"]).updateMailLogs(fileName,dateDelivered,status);
}
```

Comment: tq, I have tried like u suggested. I place the mailLog class at Initialize state. but still the datagridview didnt update the row. any idea why?

Comment: I have edited my question,provide some extra codes, hopefully it might help.tq

Comment: Is `mailLog.cs` form or simple class? I mean where did u place `dataGridView1` control?

Comment: mailLog.cs is the main form. I place the datagridview in the main form of mailLog.cs

Comment: How do you show `mailLog` form? If the form is already open then you cannot create another object of `mailLog` form and call `updateMailLogs` method. This will not update your grid data. Because the both object reference are different. You have to call that method from object of `mailLog` form which is currently loaded.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56912/discussion-between-ren-and-shell).

Comment: Yes, you are right, my form is actually already open. So, is it possible to update the form that is already open? please advice me.

Answer (score 3):

Usually this happens coz of CrossThread exception, so i guess u need to add try catch to check out, if tho u will need to invoke the grid

Edit: just noticed you asked where to put try catch
you can put it at any of your both voids , try this

```
try{
     updateLogs.updateMailLogs(fileName,dateDelivered,status);
   }
catch (Exception ex) {MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());}
```

Comment: thanks, I have edited my code like you suggested. But there's no exception thrown. Any idea please?